# Custom Sheets script for template Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I've got a worksheet that we use to store specific data for each of our events (completed jobs for the business).  After every event, we copy the Google Sheet, and create a new one. However, in making a copy, of course, it retains all the data from which it was copied. Data like how much money that Job was, it's location, etc. Therefore, I've created a simple script to clear out specific cell ranges that will receive new job specific data.

This data clearing script/button will only be used once, just after the new Sheet copy is made.

However, my frustration is that every time I make a copy, the sheet asks me to re-authorize the script. I created and maintain these sheets, I wrote the script, I make the copies of the sheets, it shouldn't require me to constantly say "yes this is ok"

- Why am I constantly being asked to authorize? It takes longer to authorize than it does to clear all the cells. (which is saying something about how long it takes to authorize.

Comment: I suggest rewriting the script to be a standalone script that creates a Google Sheets file with the necessary prefilled values and formulas. You would have a number of ux options for using it, ranging from hard coded spreadsheet id to copy from, Google drive file picker, etc. If you prefer not to do that, you can reduce the severity of the authorization scope by adding `/* @OnlyCurrentDoc */` to the start of your script file.

Comment: You are being asked to authorize the script because it is a new file and thus a new script, it has absolutely no connection to the file it was copied from.

Comment: What do you mean by a stand alone script?

Comment: This is what I'm using in the script editor. just repeated for 5 different cell ranges. And another function that calls all the clear range functions. That 'clearAll()' function is just added to a button graphic.

                    
function clearRange1() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Reports');
                       sheet.getRange('A4:B12').clearContent();
}